# Mongoose reference not placing ObjectId in parent document

Tags: express, mongoose, reference

My Mongoose model is not placing ObjectId's in the parent document for referencing to the subdocument in another collection. How can I do this?

These are my models:

menu_items.js

```
var menuItems = new mongoose.Schema({
  title : String,
  subitem: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'sub_items'}]
}, {collection: 'menu_items'});

module.exports = mongoose.model("menu_items", menuItems);
```

sub_items.js

```
var subItems = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
},{collection: 'sub_items'});

module.exports = mongoose.model("sub_items", subItems);
```

My subitem post function in ExpressJS:

```
postController.postSubitems = function(req,res,item) {
  var id = req.body.id;
  var saveData =  {
    title: req.body.sub_item
  };
  var data = new item(saveData);
  saveToDB(data,res);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to update your menuItem as well. For example, say the _id of your new sub_item is 123456. You need to update your menuItem like so:

```
menuItem.subitem.push(123456);
menuItem.save();
```

This will add the _id to the subitem array, and thus give the menuItem a reference to the specified sub_item